# Open a 360 street view in split view (cardboard style) with an intent

Tags: android, maps, google-cardboard

I need to show a client a given 360 location in an Android app that opens in split view.

This is the location:
https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=50.982625,5.490526&spn=0.18,0.3&cbll=50.982625,5.490526&layer=c&panoid=8AjpMEQkZC4AAAQXIjek5w&cbp=,51.0,,0,-0.0&output=classic&dg=ntvb

If you open this link on your Android device with the native Maps app, you can double tap the arrows and go into split view. What I would like for my app is to open this immediately. Is there a way to put that behavior in the intent?